# ploty express: set a fix color per trace when using add_trace() with scatter_mapbox

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-express

I need to plot (`scatter_mapbox`) three different dataframes. Merging is not easy, so I just use

```
fig.add_trace()
```

to add each plot to one figure. fig here is a base `choropleth_mapbox` where I add points.

```
fig_a = px.scatter_mapbox(df_a, lat="telematic_state_position_latitude", lon="telematic_state_position_longitude")
fig.add_trace(fig_a.data[0])
fig_b = px.scatter_mapbox(df_b, lat="location_latitude", lon="location_latitude")
fig.add_trace(fig_b.data[0])
fig_c = px.scatter_mapbox(df_c, lat="posisiton_latitude", lon="positionn_latitude")
fig.add_trace(fig_c.data[0])

fig.show()
```

The problem is, that the colors of all data_points are the same. As there are no similar columns, there is no easy merge option to use `color="source_column"`.

Unfortunately, graph_Object is not really an option here as the data is quite heavy and apparently express can better handle such amount of data.

**Is it possible to simply set a color in plotly express?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have full control over each dataframes visualization attributes individually. As example, the code below allows to set the color & size of `fig_a` (`df_a`) markers to be blue and 5 for `fig_b` (`df_b`) markers to be red and 10. Use them before the `fig.show` call.

```
fig['data'][0]['marker'] = {'color':'blue', 'size':5}
fig['data'][1]['marker'] = {'color':'red', 'size':10}
```